# Best way to return a dynamically sized array from C dll to VBA

Tags: arrays, c, vba

I have read a few posts on this now but none quite answer what I am after.

I am writing a C dll (not C++) to read a specific type of data file, and return the data to vba for display in excel.  For speed I would like to return the data as an array, but don't know ahead of time how big that array will be.

I have come across SAFEARRAY data type in C which seems to be the way to go but I can't figure out how to redimension it.  I am trying to use "SafeArrayRedim".  When I run it from vba it crashes at the line where it calls the dll -> it hangs for a few seconds then excel shuts down.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Is there a beter way to go about this?

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "MyDll.h" // use here the name of your header file

long __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall ResizeArray(SAFEARRAY** psaArray, long newSize)
{
    SAFEARRAYBOUND bound;
    bound.cElements = newSize;
    bound.lLbound = 0;
    long* data = (*psaArray)->pvData;
    SafeArrayRedim(*psaArray, &bou
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
    {
        data[i] = i;
    }
    return newSize;
}
```

Calling code in VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ResizeArray Lib "VBA_Test.dll" (FirstElement As Long, ByVal lElements As Long) As Long

Private Sub test()
Dim ArrayOfLongs(2) As Long
Dim lSum As Long
Dim k As Long
k = ResizeArray(ArrayOfLongs(0), 100)
End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but have you compiled and run in debug mode? I would hope for more information than just _"it crashes at the line where it calls the dll"_.

Comment: Yes I am running it in debug mode in vba - there is not any more to say than that it hangs at the line "k = ResizeArray(ArrayOfLongs(0), 100)" and then excel crashes.

Comment: Is the DLL debug-compiled? It'd be nice to see what happens when the function inside it is getting called.

Comment: Is `ArrayOfLongs(0)` just a long and not an array?

Comment: It is, but I'm passing by reference so it should be ok as passing reference to first element of array.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't realise you could debug dll as its being called from excel, so just figuring that out.  Best I have found so far is that it is this line that causes the problem: "long* data = (*psaArray)->pvData"

Comment: @bgarrood As Nathan_sav noticed, `ArrayOfLongs(0)` probably returns the _value_ stored at the first position in the array, not a pointer. I have no idea about VBA but found `VarPtr` that looks promising. Perhaps `VarPtr(ArrayOfLongs)` could be used to get a `SAFEARRAY**`

Comment: Since you now can debug the DLL, what address is `psaArray` pointing at? I think it'll be an address with the same value as `ArrayOfLongs(0)` holds.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're dead right - the address is the value of ArrayOfLongs(0).  Thank you.  I'll try VarPtr approach.

Comment: @bgarrood You're welcome! You'd better read about that `VarPtr` though. I just found it in a random post here. I have no idea if it works to pass parameters between VBA and C like that.

Comment: If you are **just** writing a dll you might find  twinbasic interesting, particularly as it has an example project for writing a standard dll in VB. Also see article at  https://nolongerset.com/how-to-standard-dll-with-twinbasic/